# How to make the parfor loop using the same random numbers as in a for loop?

Tags: matlab

In matlab, if I call

```
rng(0,'twister');
for i = 1:10
   rand(1);
   %do something
end
a=rand(1)
```

I set the random number generator to its initial state when matlab is started "rng(0,'twister')" and always get the same number "a".

Now if I use the following code

```
rng(0,'twister');
parfor i = 1:10
   rand(1);
   %do something
end
b=rand(1)
```

then I also always get the same value "b".
However, "a" does not equal "b". Can I enforce equality somehow ?

- I now I could have used rand(1,10) but this is just for demonstration. I do not want to store the random numbers before the loop.

Comment: I think that only by creating the numbers outside the parfor and sending them to the workers

Comment: See [here](http://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/115754-different-behaviour-of-rng-and-rand-in-parfor-loop) and [here](http://es.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/control-random-number-streams.html#btms9o_)

Comment: Thanks for the links, question solved.